# Selenium WebDriverException - chrome not reachable

Tags: python, linux, google-chrome, selenium

I have a chrome selenium driver on a linux server which is executed every hour by cron. The error I have occurs only on the subsequent runs, that is, during the first run it works fine, but during the 2nd or any other sub-sequential one it fails.

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436382 (70eb799287ce4c2208441fc057053a5b07ceabac),platform=Linux 4.4.0-38-generic x86_64)
```

I run it this way:

```
def create_ch_driver():
  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
  chrome_options.add_argument("--user-agent={}".format(config.USER_AGENT))
  return webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver", chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the driver is still running in the background and blocks the creation of a new webdriver instance.

Check if the process is running after the first execution of your code.

If so try to kill the process with quit():

```
webdriver.quit()
```

Comment: I'm using driver.close() each time in my script

Comment: have you checked if the process is still running?

Comment: make sense to me